# number of nilpotent $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there an elegant way of the sequence

$$c_n = \left|\{ M \in \mathbb F_2^{n\times n} : \exists k\in \mathbb N \text{ s.t. } M^k=0\}\right|$$

explicitly? (Number of nilpotent $n\times n $ matrices over $\mathbb F_2$.)

Comment: Do you know of an inelegant way?

Comment: Trying all possible combinations and counting, since it is finite for every $n$. ($2^n^2$ possible matrices for each $n$)

Comment: I am prepared to bet you have not arrived at an explicit formula in that way...

Comment: It's $2^{n^2}$..that must be computationally hard just for $c_5$.

Comment: Every nilpotent matrix is conugate to a Jordan form. For a given Jordan form you could (in theory) compute the cardinal of its stabilizer under conjugation, thus deduce the size of the orbit, and sum over all conjugacy classes of nilpotent matrices. But that's far from explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that somebody has already solved this problem! You can even find your sequence at OEIS (A053763), where they write that
$$c_n = 2^{n^2-n}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, even though I did search in OEIS I did not find this sequence! Do you know how to derive this formula? / Where to find the source? EDIT: Found it: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071579705000183